# Definition of Ito integral: adapted vs predictable processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

In Öksendal he defines the Ito integral for adapted processes, and everything works out smoothly. However, my professor tells me that in much of the standard litterature, e.g. Williams: Diffusions, Markov Processes and Martingales vol 2, the integral is only defined for predictable processes, a class strictly smaller than that of adapted processes. My question is then, why? What is the practical difference?

Comment: If I remember well, Oksendal book is integration with respect to continuous semimartingale, you need predictable condition when you integrate over jump process like Lévy process and stuff check George Lowther blog "almost sure" blog to get the full story

Comment: Ah yes, this seems to be true. In Karatzas Shreve's Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus he writes:

"In  order to  define  the  stochastic integral  with  respect to  general  martingales [...]  (possibly  discontinuous,  such  as  the  compensated Poisson process),  one  has  to  select  an even  narrower  class  of integrands  among the  so-called  predictable  processes. "

Thanks!